# How to include a link in the query string of Twitter share link?

Tags: url, twitter, parameters, hyperlink, share

I am trying to prefill a twitter post using http://twitter.com/?status=

The problem I have is that I would like to include a link in the message that will be display as a clickable link rather than just text.

My approach below doesn't work:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/?status=Share this link with your friends <a href='URL'>URL</a>">Share on Twitter</a>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use URL encoding - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding - and you don't need to add an HTML `<a href...`.

For example

```
http://twitter.com/?status=Click%20here%20https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F
```

You cannot change how the link displays.